# Download and extract a ZIP file on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a .ZIP file on a 3rd party's server, which is about ~5GB. I want to download it with a buffer (for example: 10KB) and unzip it at the same time.

Short version:
`5GB .zip file` => `Download a 10KB buffer` => `unzip` => `Download a 10KB buffer` => `unzip` => `...`

How can I do that with Ruby 2.5 and Rails 5.1?

Comment: Looks like rails is irrelevant here. It's a web framework. It has nothing for download streams.

Comment: I found `open-uri` gem but it still downloads the whole file first & doesn't allow me to interact with its buffer's data

Comment: Try https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyzip/rubyzip/Zip/File#open_buffer-class_method